# am i cheating in this number theory proof?

Tags: proof-verification, induction

the question (from burton's elementary number theory);

$verify\ that\ \forall n\ge 1,$  $$2\cdot6\cdot10\cdots(4n-2)=\frac{(2n)!}{n!}$$

my work/proof;

this is obviously true for $n=1$, so assume this is true for $n\le k$

$$2\cdots(4k-2)=\frac{(2k)!}{k!}$$

now show the formula holds for $k+1$

$$2\cdots(4k-2)(4k+2)=\frac{(2k)!(4k+2)}{k!}$$

and this is where i feel like im cheating; because i know this will be true for $k+1$ when

$$\frac{(2k!)(4k+2)}{k!}=\frac{(2k+2)!}{(k+1)!}$$

but i didn't know how to go about it directly, so this is what i did;

$$\frac{(2k!)(4k+2)}{k!}=(k+1)(k+2)\cdots(2k)(4k+2)$$

and

$$\frac{(2k+2)!}{(k+1)!}=(k+2)(k+3)\cdots(2k)(2k+1)(2k+2)$$

now assuming that the formula holds for $k+1$, i assumed that the two expressions were equal, and setting them equal to each other everything but the following cancels;

$$(k+1)(4k+2)=4k^2+6k+2$$ and,
$$(2k+1)(2k+2)=4k^2+6k+2$$ and clearly both are equal to each other and so it holds for $k+1$.

now i feel like this is cheating because, i had the formula to work with.  i mean, i was able to demonstrate, i think, that the formula holds for $k+1$ but if i were asked to come up with $$2\cdot6\cdot10\cdots(4n-2)=\frac{(2n)!}{n!}$$ or even, $$\frac{(2k!)(4k+2)}{k!}=\frac{(2k+2)!}{(k+1)!}$$ this is all much less obvious and i would not have come up with or even seen this.
thanks for your input.

Comment: Just because something involves numbers, it doesn't mean it is number theory.

Comment: As long as you have proven the formula you cited, this is not cheating. It's insightful.

Comment: oh, ok.  it did come out of a number theory book though. kinda thought that made the number theory tag relevant.  thanks.

Comment: @user74091: Just be as specific as you can with tags, but if you mess up, we can sort it out so long as you provide enough detail in the description in the problem. Some comments on MSE are very unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**.  For a simpler way, use the fact that
$$4k+2=\frac{(2k+1)(2k+2)}{k+1}\ .$$

Your proof looks as if it should be ok, **except** that it is backwards - at one point you have assumed what you wish to prove - and you need to check that everything works "the right way around".

For an easier way to do the whole thing without explicitly using induction,
$$\eqalign{2\times6\times10\times\cdots\times(4n-2)
  &=2^n\times1\times3\times5\times\cdots\times(2n-1)\cr
  &=2^n\times\frac{(2n)!}{2\times4\times6\times\cdots\times(2n)}\cr
  &=\frac{(2n)!}{n!}\ .\cr}$$

Comment: ah yes i see.  and that even should have been obvious to me when i wrote down the expressions were equal and that everything cancelled except $(k+1)(4k+2)=(2k+1)(2k+2)$ and i still didn't see that. everything is obvious in hindsight i guess.